# StartTerminateAsync throws TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND

Tags: c#, uwp, windows-runtime, .net-5

I'm trying to kill a UWP application from its AUMID using the [StartTerminateAsync](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/windows.system.appresourcegroupinfo.startterminateasync?view=winrt-17763) method, however it's throwing an error:

```
"Element not found. (0x8002802B (TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND))"
```

[image]

This is the full method:

```
    public async Task<bool> CloseApp(string aumid)
    {
        bool closeAppSuccess = true;
        Logger.Log($"Close app by aumid: {aumid}");

        // use appdiagnostics to get list of currently running apps
        IList<AppDiagnosticInfo> runningApps = await AppDiagnosticInfo.RequestInfoAsync();

        foreach (AppDiagnosticInfo item in runningApps)
        {
            string appUserModelId = item.AppInfo.AppUserModelId;
            Logger.Log($"Found running app {appUserModelId}");

            if (appUserModelId.Equals(aumid))
            {
                Logger.Log($"Found diagnostic info for current app");
                IList<AppResourceGroupInfo> resourceGroupInfos = item.GetResourceGroups();
                foreach (AppResourceGroupInfo resourceGroupInfo in resourceGroupInfos)
                {
                    Logger.Log($"Terminating resourcegroupinfo for {resourceGroupInfo}");
                    AppExecutionStateChangeResult result = await resourceGroupInfo.StartTerminateAsync();
                    if (result.ExtendedError != null)
                    {
                        Logger.LogWithScreenshot($"Failed to close the app: {result.ExtendedError.Message}");
                        closeAppSuccess = false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return closeAppSuccess;
    }
```

Comment: Not a comment on the code, but you realise that calling terminate on any process is bad right?  It's a last resort and is not advised, especially if all you want to do is a clean shutdown of a process.

Comment: It's for testing - in my case, at this point it's okay to shut the app down by any means

Comment: Maybe not a great help but TYPE_E_ELEMENTNOTFOUND is generally related to COM (IDispatch / Automation) type libraries. The error happens for example when there's a mismatch between two versions of a component, etc. so usually a setup / deployment problem

Comment: I have tested above with blank app, but we can't reproduce this problem, it looks any other cause this problem, please try to enable debug [symbol](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/debug-test-perf/deploying-and-debugging-uwp-apps#symbols) get more exception info.

Comment: I have tested the above with Slack UWP app, and it always gives that error for me.